# Is Groovy compiler able to generate warnings about deprecated code?

Tags: groovy

I am using Maven's Ant-Run plugin to build my project. The task `<groovyc>` uses Groovy compiler to compile my code. I did some investigation and it seems like Groovy compiler does not have a `deprecation` flag like `javac` does. I need my compile to fail or at least generate warnings if we are calling methods that are decorated with `@Deprecated`

Comment: groovyc have a -F and -J options and you can pass, for example, groovyc -j -FXlint Test.groovy or groovyc -j -JXlint=deprecation. Did you try it?

Comment: It seems like this option only works for cases where groovy compiler is used to compile java files.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no option to make `groovyc` less liberal if it comes to calling deprecated API. The only exception is when you use Groovy compiler to compile Java classes. By default it does not warn you about deprecated API calls - following command does not produce any output to the console:

```
groovyc SomeClass.java
```

But if you use joint compilation (`-j` switch) then Groovy compiler will fallback to Java compiler in case of Java classes:

```
groovyc -j SomeClass.java
```

Output:

```
Note: /tmp/sandbox/src/main/groovy/SomeClass.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

And then when you add `-FXlint` you will get more verbose output about what happened:

```
groovyc -j -FXlint SomeClass.java
```

Output:

```
/tmp/sandbox/src/main/groovy/SomeClass.java.java:6: warning: [deprecation] Date(int,int,int) in Date has been deprecated
    System.out.println(new Date(2018, 3, 3).getYear());
                       ^
/tmp/sandbox/src/main/groovy/SomeClass.java:6: warning: [deprecation] getYear() in Date has been deprecated
    System.out.println(new Date(2018, 3, 3).getYear());
                                           ^
4 warnings
```

However **it only applies to Java classes compiled with Groovy compiler**. Compiling Groovy classes does not give the same effect - all deprecated API calls are quietly accepted, no matter if you added `@CompileStatic` or/and `@TypeChecked` to make a final bytecode as close as possible to the Java one.